# Vector erase iterator outside range

Tags: c++, vector, msvc12

Porting some code from my game engine from Mac to Windows in C++, and I get this runtime error: "Vector erase outside range". It works on Mac!

```
void Entity::runDeferreds() {
    for (auto it = deferreds.begin(); it != deferreds.end(); /* nothing */ ) {
        if (it->Condition()) {
            it->Execution();

            it = deferreds.erase(it);
        } else {
            ++it;
        }
    }
}
```

This iterates thru a list of "deferred" tasks, which are stored in a `std::vector<DeferredCall>` called `deferreds`. If the `DeferredCall`'s `Condition()` is fulfilled, then its `Execution()` is run, and it should be removed from the `vector`. However, instead, I get the aforementioned error!

DeferredCall looks like this, not that it's too important:

```
struct DeferredCall {
    std::function<bool()> Condition;
    std::function<void()> Execution;
};
```

Help?!

**EDIT:- Alternative Method**

I also tried this, again working on Mac:

```
deferreds.erase(std::remove_if(deferreds.begin(), deferreds.end(),
    [](DeferredCall &call) {
            if (call.Condition()) {
                call.Execution();
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    ), deferreds.end());
```

However, in this case I get "vector iterators incompatible".

Comment: Shouldn't you break out of the loop after erase(it)? Otherwise you are re-iterating over the same erased iterator again.

Comment: Do the callbacks have access (even indirectly) to `deferreds`. Could it be modified within a callback?

Comment: Alternative method is an implementation of erase remove idiom. It looks fine!!

Comment: @DanSimmons: `std::vector::erase` returns an iterator following the removed element which this code assigns to `it`. This code looks like it correctly implements a common idiom.

Comment: Both of those look ok.  Is this your actual code or just an example?  The reason I ask is that most of the time when you see the "iterators incompatible" message it's because the vector is being returned by value rather than reference from a get function.

Comment: Ah OK yeah in that case I'm at a loss.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Could it be that the deferreds object is invalid? for example if deferreds is stored in Entity which is no longer valid (already freed). Add a "bool valid;" member variable in Entity and set it to true in the constructor and false in the destructor. Then check if still true in the runDeferreds function.

Answer (score 5):

Although it doesn't answer where your error comes from, you may try to rework the code as follows:

```
const auto pred = [](Deferred& d){ return !d.Condition(); };
auto itMatch = std::partition( defs.begin(), defs.end(), pred);

const auto action = [](Deferred& d){ d.Execution(); };
std::for_each(itMatch, defs.end(), action);

defs.erase(itMatch, defs.end());
```

Also, [std::vector::erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/) is guaranteed to return perfectly valid iterator. Could be `vector::end()` though.

Links: [std::partition](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/partition/), [std::for_each](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/), [std::vector::erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/)

Comment: Good idea. This avoids the undefined behavior of calling a non-const function on the object in the predicate passed to `std::remove_if`