# Why do I get a runtime error: Vector erase iterator outside range

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, stdvector

I have faced with a strange runtime error for the following code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

struct Data
{
    int id;
};

int main()
{
    vector<Data> mylist;

    Data m;
    m.id = 10;

    mylist.push_back(m);

    mylist.erase(std::remove_if(
        mylist.begin(),
        mylist.end(),
        [](const Data &m) {
        return m.id>100;
    }));

    return 0;
}
```

The error says:

> Vector erase iterator outside range

[image: Screenshot]

I am not after solving the problem like [Ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44851975/vector-erase-iterator-outside-range-error), [Ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28246467/vector-erase-iterator-outside-range) but realizing the cause of the problem and whether I have done something wrong.

Comment: @HenriMenke, I have fixed the MWE to create the same error.

Comment: Alright, I converted my downvote into an upvote :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct form is

```
mylist.erase(
    std::remove_if(mylist.begin(),mylist.end(),lambda),
    mylist.end());
```

You need to pass the `end` to the erase too.

Answer (score 2):

In the above example, the **remove_if** function template will return an invalid iterator. Now as per the documentation of [std::vector::erase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) the iterator pos must be valid and dereferenceable which is in your case is not valid and because of which the assert message is thrown.

Alternatively, you can just provide the [end()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end) iterator as second argument to the [std::vector::erase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) function or use [std::vector::pop_back](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/pop_back) to pop the element from the vector.